# Passing pointer of dynamic var by reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to create dynamic variable and pass its address by reference within `new_test` function, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test
{   
    int a;
    int b;
};  

void new_test(test *ptr, int a, int b)
{   
    ptr = new test;
    ptr -> a = a;
    ptr -> b = b;
    cout << "ptr:   " << ptr << endl; // here displays memory address
};  

int main()
{   

    test *test1 = NULL;

    new_test(test1, 2, 4); 

    cout << "test1: " << test1 << endl; // always 0 - why?
    delete test1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All these pointer questions are no good (Please get used to RAII) -1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code does not pass the pointer by reference so changes to the parameter `ptr` are local to the function and not visible to the caller. Change to:

```
void new_test (test*& ptr, int a, int b)
                  //^
```

Comment: @Davlog, yes it would but it would require dereferencing within the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
void new_test (test *ptr, int a, int b)
{   
    ptr = new test; //<< Here ptr itself is a local variable, and changing it does not affect the value outside the function
    //...
```

You are changing the pointer value itself, so you need a pointer to pointer, or a reference to a pointer:

**Pointer of a pointer:**

```
void new_test (test **ptr, int a, int b)
{   
    *ptr = new test;
    (*ptr) -> a = a;
    (*ptr) -> b = b;
    cout << "ptr:   " << *ptr << endl; // here displays memory address
}
```

and call using:

```
new_test (&test1, 2, 4);
```

**Reference to a pointer:**

```
void new_test (test *& ptr, int a, int b) {/.../ }
```

I don't recommend mixing pointer and reference, because it makes the program hard to read and track. But it is personal preference.