# Values is destroyed despite allocating on the heap

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

Sorry but I thought I understood this with stack and heap by now but obviously I am wrong. I declared every object on the heap but all the same when the first metod is done I can see via std::cout that the time is ZERO, that is:

```
startTPtr: 00:00:00
```

When the time is printed within the function its ok but somehow it becomes destroyed after the functions ends.

Did I miss something crucial here? Should I return the pointer from the function?

Thanks in advance!!!

```
int main() {

   Clock *_clockPtr = new Clock();

   MyTime *_startTPtr = new MyTime();
   MyTime *_endTPtr = new MyTime();

   char *ch = new char[100];

   start_app(_startTPtr, _endTPtr, _clockPtr, ch);

   cout << "startTPtr: " << *_startTPtr << endl;

return 0;
}

void start_app(MyTime *_startTPtr, MyTime *_endTPtr, Clock *clock, char *ch) {

   cout << "Press ENTER to start and finish!";
   int newLine = 0;
   for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {

    if (newLine == 0) {
        std::cout << "... ";
        MyTime* myTime1 = new MyTime(clock->give_me_the_time()); 
        _startTPtr = myTime1;
        cin >> ch;
    } else {
        MyTime* myTime2 = new MyTime(clock->give_me_the_time()); 
        _endTPtr = myTime2;
        break;
    }
    cout << "startTPtr: " << *_startTPtr << endl;
    newLine++;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing pointer of dynamic var by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722208/passing-pointer-of-dynamic-var-by-reference) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250284/scope-of-heap-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change an argument in a function and have it reflected in the caller of the function, you need to pass the argument *by reference*. Otherwise the arguments are *copied* and you only change the copies.

In your `start_app` function you want to change both `_startTPtr` and `_endTPtr` so you need to pass them as references to pointers to `MyTime`:

```
void start_app(MyTime *&_startTPtr, MyTime *&_endTPtr, Clock *clock, char *ch) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks :-) .. will accept in 5 minutes

Comment: could an alternative be to make an explicit copy-constructor?